# Check if we find new value from a request

Tags: python

I have created a script where I add a timestamp to each value that has been found with a code that I have written:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Dict, List
import time

class RequestFilter:
    """Tracks requests and filters them to prevent hammering."""

    def __init__(self, cooldown: timedelta):
        self._cooldown = cooldown
        self._requests: Dict[str, datetime] = {}

    def filter(self, requests: List[str], time: datetime) -> List[str]:
        """Filter requests to only those that haven't been made
        previously within our defined cooldown period."""
        # Get filtered set of requests.
        filtered = [
            r for r in list(set(requests))
            if (
                    r not in self._requests or time - self._requests[r] >= self._cooldown
            )
        ]
        # Refresh timestamps for requests we're actually making.
        for r in filtered:
            self._requests[r] = time
            
        print(self._requests)
        return filtered


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import sleep
    request_filter = RequestFilter(timedelta(minutes=5))

    firstReq = []
    for _ in range(random.randint(1,5)):
        firstReq.append(f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}")

    for _ in range(100):

        newReq = []
        for _ in range(random.randint(2, 8)):
            newReq.append(f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}")

        if len(newReq) > len(firstReq):
            print(request_filter.filter(newReq, datetime.now()), datetime.now())
            sleep(1)
            firstReq = newReq
        else:
            print("Length is not bigger, testing again in 3 sec...")
            time.sleep(3)
            firstReq = newReq
```

As you can see at the very bottom i'm checking if the list size from previous request is less than newest request (at this momentit just random function but it would be reading from a HTML later on) and if it is, that means that something has been added to a webpage and we want to see what value has been added. If the value has already a timestamp then we check "filter" and see if it has been over 5 minutes difference in the timestamp and if its true then we should say "New value has been found!"

However my improvements in general here is that I am not quite happy with the way that I check for length of firstReq vs newReq. and reason if that could be etc if I request a page and it has US 3 and then the newReq has value US 6 but it still will have 1 > 1 which is false but still different value which will not print due to the 1 > 1. My question is, how can I improve the code that I could skip the < function and check maybe the sizes directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Global code

Move the code after your `__main__` check into a function, since it's still in global scope.

### PEP8

`firstReq` should be `first_req`, and the same for `new_req`.

### Dict comprehension

I would rearrange your `filtered` comprehension to be only a dict, and to use `dict.update`. In other words,

```
filtered = {r: self._requests.get(r) for r in requests}

self._requests.update({
    r: time
    for r, orig_time in filtered.items()
    if orig_time is None or time - orig_time >= self._cooldown
})
```

### List comprehension

```
    firstReq = []
    for _ in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
        firstReq.append(f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}")
```

can be

```
first_req = [
    f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}"
    for _ in range(random.randint(1, 5))
]
```

### Diagnostic printing

```
    print(self._requests)
```

is out-of-place. Remove it, and if you still want this to happen, issue an equivalent statement from `main()`, perhaps printing the entire `RequestFilter` and overriding `__str__` to return `pprint.pformat(self._requests)`.

### Change detection

Apparently what you actually want is to return a boolean that is true if `self._requests` has changed. This can be done like:

```
filtered = {r: self._requests.get(r) for r in requests}

old_requests = dict(self._requests)

self._requests.update({
    r: time
    for r, orig_time in filtered.items()
    if orig_time is None or time - orig_time >= self._cooldown
})

return old_requests == self._requests
```

Comment: Hello! I appreciate the advice and I will be right on it! About the pep8 I do agree. I was used to use the camelCase but will be changed to underscore instead :) About the `Dict comprehension` I tried to run the code you provided and it does give me an error `self._requests.update({ TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` Im not sure what could be a cause of it at this moment. But also what should we return in that case if we in our case remove the filtered?

Comment: The `List comprehension` would it be really needed to have a list of different values if we check timestamp for each value that has been found anyways? In that case I wouldn't need `if len(newReq) > len(firstReq):` at all and incase I could just do the timestamp comprehension ? :D

Comment: Re. the `TypeError` - my mistake; I needed to use `.items()`. Please try again.

Comment: Im having abit trouble to understand your `Dict comprehension` compare to what I have done. as I understood, im checking the currently request and compare it to the `self._requests` and if there is new value added then it will be added to the filtered list - which we can then return and assume its true (Meaning that there has been something being added from the filter function) else if there is no value added then it will return empty filtered list which will be False. Im not sure if you do the same?

Comment: If you're looking to return an indicator that `self._requests` has changed, there's a better way to do it. I'll update.

Comment: I would say I just want to know if there has been an update for a value or not, if it has been a update then return True or False if there havent been an update basically :) I think that would be enough for me.

Comment: I would need more testing but I think it might look better! I did get an error saying: Expected type 'List[str]', got 'bool' instead  for `def filter(self, requests: List[str], time: datetime) -> List[str]:` instead of List[str] it should be bool, would the change be a problem?

Comment: You'd need to update your return type hint, of course. And if you want to compare one dict to another, yes, you need `old_requests` to be a dict.

Comment: I will give it a try, its looking lots promising compare to what I had before actually :) Thank you very much for the review! - If I might ask, im just curious, what is the difference between what I had before vs. what you did? Is it better performens to have it the way you showed? Or faster, please let me know :D

Comment: Also after testing, it seems to return False even though it has added a new value into the dict or changed the timestamp. Are you sure that it is working as expected? I assume it should be != instead of == if we want to see if we have added a new value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115658/discussion-between-reinderien-and-protractornewbie).